# Move turtles to other turtles

Tags: netlogo, turtle-graphics

I created a model where birds shall fly on a certain route. I created this route by placing 10 turtles I called "rasts" (resting place) on patches an linking them with each other. Now, I want to make the birds fly on these routes and when a resting place disappears (by using an "on/off" switch), they shall take another route. 
The birds don't fly on the route I created at the moment.

My question is:

Is it possible to make turtles (birds) follow a route an change it, when there's another turtle (rast) in there way?

My code with the "move" command:

```
breed [rasts rast]
breed [birds bird]

to setup
 setup-birds
 setup-rasts
 set-links
end 

to setup-rasts
 set-default-shape rasts "circle"                  
 create-rasts 1 [setxy -12 36 ]

to set-links
 ask rast (number-of-birds + 0) [    
 create-link-with rast (number-of-birds + 1)         
 ] 
end

to move-on-links                       
   stop move-birds                       
   ask birds
   at-points [[-12 36]]                  
  (facexy -17 16) and (fd 1)
end
```

Comment: Please always read the tag description when adding tags to your description: [tag:turtle] is for the RDF syntax of that name, while you probably mean [tag:turtle-graphics] (I also [retagged your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28517905/revisions) a few days ago.)

Comment: On solution can be to `heading` birds  `towards` rats ?  Your example is a bit too poor and I can not help you more.